# Chaining in Promise not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm facing an issue with promises..and was banging my head around from almost an hour now...

```
this.getDocument(documentId)
.then(function (response) {
     console.log('in first then')
     return 'from first then';
}).then(function (response) {
     console.log(response)
});
```

Ideally the above code should give following output

```
  in first then
  from first then
```

But the actual output is as follows

```
  in first then
  undefined
```

Now the problem here is why the second `then` is getting response as undefined when I'm returning something from the first `then`.

> **[EDIT 1]** Adding getDoument code

```
function getDocument(documentID) {
        var config = {
            url: '<URL>' + documentID,
            headers: {enter code here
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        return HttpRequest.get(config);
    }

var HttpRequest = (function () {
    function HttpRequest() {
    }
    HttpRequest.get = function (config) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = config.url;
        var authToken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
        http.open("GET", url, true);
        Object.keys(config.headers).map(function (k) {
            http.setRequestHeader(k, config.headers[k]);
        });
        http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + authToken);
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState !== 4)
                return;
            var response = http.responseText;
            if (http.status != 200)
                return deferred.reject(response);
            deferred.resolve(response);
            // if (/^[^2]\d\d$/.exec(http.status)) return deferred.reject(http.status);
        };
        http.send();
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    HttpRequest.post = function (config) {
    };
    return HttpRequest;
}());
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible; are there more details you're omitting?

Comment: Works with a stubbed `getDocument` here: https://jsfiddle.net/cf9ay8uq/

Comment: Is `this.getDocument` returning a _real_ Promise?

Comment: this.getDocument is not Promise ...

Comment: this.getDocument is returning a Promise only...first then is working fine..the problem is with second then only

Comment: @torazaburo: just because a function returns something with a then method doesn't mean it necessarily works like a promise is supposed to. If it's not logging the return value, then it is not compliant. I'm guessing there's more to this story, though.

Comment: @RishiTiwari: you'll need to share details about what `this.getDocument` does.

Comment: this.getDocument is making a http call to get some data...and I'm using Q.deffer() there to return promise...do you thing that could be an issue..?

Comment: @torazaburo: using Q library to return promise...and using the deferred pattern.

Comment: Added code for GetDocument

Comment: what arguments is the second then function being called with?

Comment: @ Dayan Moreno Leon : its just that whatever  I'm returning from the first then..should be an input for the second then.

Comment: your core code should output exactly what you expect ... odd thing is, you've tagged this as `node.js` - but `node.js` doesn't have `XMLhttpRequest` or `window.localStorage` ... so I take it you are using Q in a browser ... may I suggest using native promises instead (all but IE support it, and there's a decent polyfill or two that actually work)

Comment: @ Jaromanda X: I'm using electronjs to build my application..in electronjs I can write code in nodejs and the application itself runs on the browser, hence you can access the window.localstorage.